# how to connect to gmail outbox via php imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I'm following http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap to connect to gmail and download some emails. I have:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'davidwalshblog@gmail.com';
$password = 'davidwalsh';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
```

this seems to work for the inbox, but when i try the outbox with:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}SENT';
```

I get:

```
Warning: include(application/errors/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Could someone advise me on how to connect to the gmail outbox?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request with a third party IMAP system namely Google Mail (Gmail). Even that is a popular one, this is not a programming question but asking for configuration of a system nobody of us has control over.

Comment: It's a a question about IMAP API programming, so as much "on topic" as can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gmail sentbox is usually named "[Gmail]/Sent".

Comment: @Max: Can you outline how to find that out with the help of the imap extension? So if another user looks for the spam or xyz folder for example, so that it offers more?

Comment: The IMAP LIST command will tell you all the mailboxes in the account.  You will have to find the PHP function that corresponds to that.  Google specifically tags the "system" folders with special flags to help you identify the Sent, Trash, etc. mailboxes.